# Convert a Date to nanoseconds in R

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I am trying to convert a date to nanoseconds in R. I tried using lubridate package but not successful.

> dateval <- c("2016-06-29")

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? A date is a fixed point in time. Nanoseconds implies some sort of measurement between 2 points in time, doesn't it? Do you want nanoseconds since that date? BTW it's preferred for you to show your prior attempt instead of just saying you tried something. It's often helpful to people who want to help you.

Comment: The other point to make is that R uses system functions for some of its datetime work and I know of no systems that store datetimes at nanosecond precision. Millisecond accuracy is generally what you get since that is the POSIX time level of precision..

Comment: You want the amount of nanosecond, but starting from when? Also since you want nanosecond precision, the date you provide should in theory provide the same precision.

Comment: Sorry for not adding all the details before. We are trying to inject the output from my forecasting script into Influx DB which is a timeseries db. It looks for the difference in nanoseconds from "1970-01-01" and identifies the date.  i am looking at the difference in dates from 1970-01-01 to 2016-06-29 represented in nanoseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup:

```
require(lubridate)
dateval  <- c("2016-06-29")
dateeval <- ymd(dateval)
```

A nanosecond is a SI unit of time equal to one billionth of a second.

Time different between the epoch and that date in nanoseconds (approximate since there was no timestamp with the dates):

```
difftime(dateeval, Sys.time(), units = "secs")
abs(as.numeric(difftime(ymd("1970-01-01"),dateeval, units = "secs")))*1000000000
[1] 1.467158e+18
```

Comment: This is wrong as a POSIXct is accurate only to about 1.1 microseconds. You can multiply by as much as you want but the last four digits will be garbage with the 53 bits precision in a `double`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thought it was pretty clear in the answer that this is an approximation as there's not even a timestamp for the date anyway

Comment: Not so. The [nanotime package](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/nanotime) can in fact answer this _because it goes beyond the POSIXct resolution_. With it I can do `nanotime(Sys.time()) - nanotime(Sys.Date())` to get the proper (in `integer64` resolution) _and precise_ nanoseconds since midnight. No approximation here.  In that sense your answer is wrong as I claim, and this one is correct despite your claims.  (There is a remaining error due to a local vs utc difference also creeping in but that is a parameterization issue we can fix easily.)

Comment: It works once we simplify via `Sys.setenv("TZ"="UTC")`.  Then `Sys.time() - as.POSIXct(Sys.Date())` gives me a nicely formatted result from `difftime()`.  And using `nanotime()` works the same way, with scaling:  `(nanotime(Sys.time()) -  nanotime(Sys.Date()))/(1e9*3600)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `microbenchmark` package.  The package returns benchmarks of how long it takes to execute something to a fine precision.  Inside the package they have a function that will return the current time in nanoseconds

```
microbenchmark::get_nanotime()
[1] 3.610932e+14
microbenchmark::get_nanotime()
[1] 3.610952e+14
microbenchmark::get_nanotime()
[1] 3.610958e+14
microbenchmark::get_nanotime()
[1] 3.610963e+14
```

Alternatively, if precision becomes less important you can use

`as.numeric(as.POSIXct(TIMEA)) - as.numeric(as.POSIXct(TIMEB))`

Comment: I understand that this relates to a comment made by the OP, but it doesn't actually answer the official question. BTW what did you mean by beomes?